# Apache Pulsar: application using DotPulsar

Tags: .net-core, apache-pulsar

I build a small NET Core app to test Pulsar. I am trying to repeat steps described here https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/client-libraries-dotnet/
I have added the NuGet DotPulsar.

And I have errors during the compilation.
For example,
var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World");
var messageId = await pulsarProducer.NewMessage()
.Property("SomeKey", "SomeValue")
.Send(data);

IProducer does not contains definition for NewMessage() etc. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The 'NewMessage' method on IProducer is actually an extension method, so you need a using statement for 'DotPulsar.Extensions'.

Best regards
db